# Webrtc. Video data not sent from ipad safari

Tags: ios, ipad, video, safari, webrtc

I have a small web app that uses webrtc-based to allow up to 4 people to see/hear each other. Everything works fine in most cases except when an ipad is involved. Here are a few test scenarios:

User 1 (chrome on windows), User 2 (ipad 14, safari), User 3 (MacOS, Safari). User 1 can see/hear and be seen/heard by all. User 2 can see/hear all but is not seen by User 3 (audio is fine). User 3 can be seen/heard by all. I logged stats from each peer connection and, for outbound-rtp of type video, no data is sent from User 2 to User 3 (but audio is sent fine and audio/video is sent fine to User 1).

If User 3 switches to using an iPad as well, now User 2 and 3 cannot see each other (no outbound video data sent between these 2 users) though they can still hear each other.

If we have 2 Windows/Chrome machines and 1 iPad, all is fine.

So, it seems that iPads won't send video to another Safari instance (be it Mac or Ipad), but can send audio fine and can send audio and video to Chrome. All signaling states are as expected, all peer connection statuses are Completed, ontrack is called as expected for both audio and video tracks. Audio and video are captured fine (since User 1 sees/hears them). I can't figure out why the video data is not sent from the ipad to another Safari.

Has anybody run into this or has any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question in case someone else runs into this. After much digging, I found a way to make it work.

In my app, the video is rendered pretty small, so I was setting a video constraint  width:160 in getUserMedia. The call itself worked fine (no exception thrown) and the video captured ok but for some reason it would not send that video data to other Safari browsers. I changed it to 320 and it all started working.
The tradeoff is of course wasted bandwidth but at least it works.

Comment: Hey, That's nice you experience this issue, could you please send me the code example, I am having the same issue. Plus Mac Safari browser to iPad Safari did you test that combination too?

Comment: @MuhammadAdil. I think was an issue from Safari to Safari on Mac and Ipad. Here's some sample code. Really just setting constraint based on safari variable.                  let videoContraints = isSafari ? { width: 320 } : { width: 160 };  
let constraints = {  video: videoContraints };
 let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, but I think that should be handled automatically by aws-chime-sdk-js in the 2.8.0 version